# Get reverse URL name from full path

Tags: python, django

Does anyone knows how I can get the URL name from the request.get_full_path()?

For example:

I have this URL in urls.py

```
url(r'^evaluation-active/$', 'web.evaluation.evaluation', name='evaluation'),
```

In my context_processor.py:

```
def is_evaluation(request):
    return {"test":request.get_full_path()}
```

How can I return "evaluation" instead of "/evaluation-active/"?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.resolver_match):

> **HttpRequest.resolver_match**
>
> New in Django 1.5. An instance of ResolverMatch representing the
>   resolved url. This attribute is only set after url resolving took
>   place, which means it’s available in all views but not in middleware
>   methods which are executed before url resolving takes place (like
>   process_request, you can use process_view instead).

There is `url_name` attribute in `ResolverMatch` object:

```
def is_evaluation(request):
    return {"test": request.resolver_match.url_name}
```

For django version < 1.5 there is answer here: [How to get the current urlname using Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491605/how-to-get-the-current-urlname-using-django)

Comment: Thanks, and you know how to redirect in the context_processor.py? It doesn't work

Comment: @MarcosAguayo hm, im dont know, why you want to redirect in context processor instead of view?

Comment: I want to check if user had approve the evaluation, if not redirect to the page. I have 20 pages, I'm trying not to repeat the code.

Comment: @MarcosAguayo example of redirect middleware: https://github.com/redsolution/django-redirect-middleware/blob/master/redirects/middleware.py

Answer (score 1):

If using django 1.5 or higher, use request.resolver_match to get the ResolverMatch object.

```
def is_evaluation(request):
    return {"test":request.resolver_match.url_name}
```

if using version before 1.5, then use resolve:

```
def is_evaluation(request):
    return {"test":resolve(request.path_info).url_name}
```