# Django - Pass URL "name" attribute to view

Tags: python, django, view, django-urls

I've the following URL that i created:

## urls.py

```
url(r'^authors', GenericView.as_view(model=Author, context_object_name='authors_list',
     success_url=reverse_lazy('author_link'),
     template_name='app/authors.html'), name='author_url_name'),
```

And i want to have access to the URL's name on the view, passed in a variable. In this case, **'author_url_name'**.

The view function where i need it, is the following:

## views.py

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(AuthorClass, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['action'] = reverse_lazy('author_url_name')
    return context
```

This works, but i want to replace the 'author_url_name' for some method that gives me exactly that.

Thanks for your time!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17614086/183948 has your answer for you.

> As of Django 1.5, this can be accessed from the request object
>
> ```
> current_url = request.resolver_match.url_name
> ```
>
> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.resolver_matc

Comment: Thanks Brad for your answer. But, the class where i use the function get_context_data(self, **kwargs) is a CreateView, and it's not passed a 'request'. So, when i do `context['action'] = reverse_lazy(request.resolver_match.url_name)`, it doesn't recognize the `request`bit. How do i solve this? Sorry, i'm a newbie.

Comment: You can get it from `self.request`.