# How to get URL name in template?

Tags: django

I tried to print this in the template, but it renders blank. Whats the correct way to get URL name in template?

```
{{ request.resolver_match.url_name }}
```

I wanted it to highlight something in the top bar (if path is 'admin-stuff' add highlight class).

Comment: Could you show how do you return a response from the view?

Comment: Do you mean the url name, or the url path?

Comment: @rnevius I'm pretty sure the OP means the `name` since there is `request.resolver_match.url_name` provided.

Comment: But then he mentions something about `if path is...`, which got me confused.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django: How can I identify the calling view from a template?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/792410/django-how-can-i-identify-the-calling-view-from-a-template)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the application settings `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` must include

```
"django.core.context_processors.request"
```

for the `request` to appear in the template context.