# Django Get name of current view as a string

Tags: python, django, view

Is it possible to get the name of Django view in string form?
I have searched a lot but could not find the answer.

Comment: There isn't anything built-in to do that. You can get the current app, but you'd have to write a context processor or something to get the view.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django: How can I identify the calling view from a template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/792410/django-how-can-i-identify-the-calling-view-from-a-template)

Comment: `request.resolver_match.func.__name__` inside a view could work but you should tell why you need it, maybe there is a better pattern

Comment: Thank you very much @PRMoureu , it worked like a charm.

Comment: What about, `self.get_view_name()` ? (in  **CBV**)

Answer (score 4):

The above did not work for me, but I was able to find some solutions by running `dir` on `request`.

```py
 request.resolver_match.view_name
```

seems to give me the correct name for the view.

Comment: This one worked for me 

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
request.view
```

Example:

```
if request.view == "my_view":
    #do things
```

Answer (score 0):

If you get view as a function from `resolve` you can check it like this:

```
view, _, _ = resolve(request.path)
view_name = view.__name__
```